# In scattering experiments, why can't we measure the wavepackets of the particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section

In John Taylor's Scattering Theory book, he says that the wave packets of the particle that enters the collision and the one of the particle that leaves the collision cannot, in practice, be uniquely identified and that is why we formulate our problem in terms of the differential cross section.

But, is this still true that we can't identify the wavepackets if we only have one particle going in and one coming out? And if so, why?